# If condition for this basic neural network but it isn't working

Tags: c#

For some reason this if statement is invalid and it says: "Use of unassigned local variable 'I1'.

I can't figure out what is wrong with this if statement and it's bothering me.

I am using VisualStudio 2019, and I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
bool I1;

if (I1 == true)
{

}
```

Comment: Did you mean to set it?  `bool I1 = true;`

Comment: What do you think the value of `I1` is when you get to the 'if' statement? You haven't assigned a value to it. It is capable of storing a value, but you haven't given it one, and the compiler recognizes that

Comment: By the way, the "basic neural network" part of your title adds misleading information; your question has nothing to do with neural networks. You should remove it. And (nit-picking), whoever picks up maintenance on your code won't appreciate a variable named _capital-i_ plus _numeral-1_

Answer (score 0):

The line 'Bool I1;' creates a variable, but doesn't assign it any value. Your if statement is asking "does this thing with no value equal something" and the compiler is politely letting you know that it's not bothered to do that. Presumably you'd want something like

```
bool I1 = GetValueOfI1Method();
if(I1) //if(I1) is functionally equivalent to if(I1 == true) but generally more readible
{
     //do stuff
}
```

I'm guessing/hoping you have some code that could potentially assign a value to I1, if you want to use your if statement anyway  what you can do is use a nullable boolean

```
bool? I1 = null; //use a nullable bool
//code which might assign a value to foo
...
//if statement to check if a value has been assigned and if it's true
if(I1.HasValue && I1.Value) //has anyone assigned a value to I1 and if so is that value true
{

}
```

Realistically you'd never bother to do the above with a bool, you'd just set it to false and run a method that might possibly set it to true (or the inverse)